# can a video projector take input?

Tags: image-processing, video-processing

Can a Video projector take input?.. I want to create an augmented reality application where the user will click on the buttons projected in the screen. 
Is this possible only with the projector ? or a camera is also needed?

I know that without camera it's not possible. But i don't know much abt the projectors that's why i am asking this question

Comment: How would you install the software into the projector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Projectors can only project... they work with a strong light-bulb that projects the image onto the screen/wall...

If you want some sort of input, you need a camera or another sensor. This could even be a Nintendo Wii Remote:
http://johnnylee.net/projects/wii/
(Have a look at the second project there)

But your projector itself is not capable of getting input... maximum would be infrared from remote controls, but that depends on the projector

Answer (score 0):

You need something like a camera (can also be kinect or something like that) or something like a "touchable wallpaper" (don't know if there is something on the market).

Ciao!
  Stefan

Answer (score 0):

http://smarttech.com/us/Solutions/Education+Solutions/Products+for+education/Interactive+whiteboards+and+displays/SMART+Board+interactive+whiteboards

This is pretty well solved.